# Rad XE5 undefined reference error (E2597) when compiling on VMWare

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

Today I ported XE5 installation onto the VMWare Windows 7 x86 OS. I did not install android SDKs, but rather created one from already existing SDK on my host OS, via Network Drive mapping.

The network drive S on VMWare OS is basically the clone (link) to my physical hard drive C of the host OS, so the paths should be ok. The SDK was created successfully, however I get some (a lot, probably all there is) linker errors when trying to compile.

I'm opening existing projects from S drive as well, practically the same as I did on my host OS before. I can run Sample project, FlashLight for example, either from VM C disk, or the same, S disk location with no linker errors, so I'm guessing it's something in my project.

Can anybody tell why Rad XE5 has undefined reference error (E2597), and how could I bypass this?

Error log below:

```
 [DCC Error] E2597 S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStartCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:139: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstAddRef(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStartCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:142: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstClear(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStartCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:142: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstClear(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStopCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:145: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstAddRef(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStopCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:148: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstClear(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::btnStopCameraClick(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:148: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstClear(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::FormCreate(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:67: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstAddRef(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::Timer1Timer(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:82: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstAddRef(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::ToArray():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2280: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TEnumerator<>::TEnumerator(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1185: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TEnumerator<>::TEnumerator(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1186: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TEnumerator<>::TEnumerator(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1188: error: undefined reference to 'System::_AfterConstruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TEnumerator<>::TEnumerator(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1188: error: undefined reference to 'System::_ClassDestroy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::~TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:813: error: undefined reference to 'System::_BeforeDestruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, signed char)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::~TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:817: error: undefined reference to 'System::_ClassDestroy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::ToArray():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1168: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::Error(System::UnicodeString, NativeInt):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:821: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseAtExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, void*)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:783: error: undefined reference to 'System::_AfterConstruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:783: error: undefined reference to 'System::_ClassDestroy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TList__1(System::DelphiInterface<System::Generics::Defaults::IComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:797: error: undefined reference to 'System::_AfterConstruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TList__1(System::DelphiInterface<System::Generics::Defaults::IComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:797: error: undefined reference to 'System::_ClassDestroy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::TList__1(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:810: error: undefined reference to 'System::_AfterConstruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::Insert(int, System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:874: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::InsertRange(int, System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> const*, int):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:892: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::DeleteRange(int, int):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1032: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::Move(int, int):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1122: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::Variant>::TKeyCollection<>::TKeyCollection(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::Variant> >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2238: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstWeakCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::Variant>::TValueCollection<>::TValueCollection(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::Variant> >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2209: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstWeakCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::TObject> >::~TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:813: error: undefined reference to 'System::_BeforeDestruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, signed char)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::TObject> >::Error(System::UnicodeString, NativeInt):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:821: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseAtExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, void*)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TComponent> >::~TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:813: error: undefined reference to 'System::_BeforeDestruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, signed char)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TComponent> >::Error(System::UnicodeString, NativeInt):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:821: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseAtExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, void*)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TCollectionItem> >::~TList__1():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:813: error: undefined reference to 'System::_BeforeDestruction(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, signed char)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TCollectionItem> >::Error(System::UnicodeString, NativeInt):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:821: error: undefined reference to 'System::_RaiseAtExcept(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>, void*)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<int, System::DelphiInterface<System::Classes::IInterfaceList> >::TKeyCollection<>::TKeyCollection(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<int, System::DelphiInterface<System::Classes::IInterfaceList> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2238: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstWeakCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<int, System::DelphiInterface<System::Classes::IInterfaceList> >::TValueCollection<>::TValueCollection(System::DelphiObject<System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<int, System::DelphiInterface<System::Classes::IInterfaceList> > >):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2209: error: undefined reference to 'System::_InstWeakCopy(System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>&, System::DelphiObject<System::TObject>)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function Cameracomp::TCameraComponentForm::GetImage():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:160: error: undefined reference to 'Fmx::Media::TCameraComponent::SampleBufferToBitmap(System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Graphics::TBitmap>, bool)'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Fmx::Types::TFmxObject'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Fmx::Types::TFmxObject'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<System::TObject> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::TObject'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<System::TObject> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::TObject'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TComponent> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TComponent'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TComponent> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TComponent'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TCollectionItem> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TCollectionItem'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TCollectionItem> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TCollectionItem'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TBasicActionLink> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TBasicActionLink'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Classes::TBasicActionLink> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Classes::TBasicActionLink'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TEqualityComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Types::TFmxObject> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1692: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Fmx::Types::TFmxObject'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Actions::TContainedAction> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Actions::TContainedAction'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Defaults::TComparer__1<System::DelphiObject<System::Actions::TContainedAction> >::Default():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:1680: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for System::Actions::TContainedAction'
      S:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: S:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2\Android\Debug\CameraComp.o: in function System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::DelphiObject<Fmx::Forms::TCommonCustomForm> >::HasWeakRef():C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas:2308: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Fmx::Forms::TCommonCustomForm'
```

There are 7x as much lines as there are above...

Comment: Among each line, I can see some path mistype, if I'm not mistaken:
DelphiObject<System::TObject>):C:\Delphi\Android\BitStack\V0.2/CameraComp.pas -> where there's backslash instead of slash, but don't know where to change that...

Comment: What is your "host OS", and what does "ported" mean? (I understand "ported my app from Windows to Android", but I don't understand "ported a product installation to".)

Comment: Sounds to me like you avoided installing an SDK (possibly for licensing reasons) and instead tried to manually reference the SDK files. If so, let's just say there's a reason why many SDK's need to be installed, to avoid license hacking.

Comment: Host OS is Windows 7 x64; It's the system that VMWare is running on;
By 'ported' I just meant that I did the installation of XE5 there. Now that I'm reading your sentence, I see that I probably could/should use different word... sorry, English is not my native language.. :)
All I meant was that I installed XE5 onto VMWare's windows installation, but didn't add SDK there, I access to SDK folders via Network drive.

Comment: @JerryDodge by licensing reasons you mean what? Android SDK's are free...?
The main reason was that it failed to install (extract indeed) due to low virtual disk space at firstly, but later I decided to rather point it to a location where I already have SDKs, since I also wanted to avoid having another 2GB's taken, as I have SSD which is not that big (and 2 by 2 gigs, it comes overtaken rather fast).
And android SDK's doesn't really need to be installed (confirmed info). At least not if not using emulator (in that case not sure though...)

Comment: That was just a guess, I've never developed for or even used an Android, so I've never even looked into the SDK. But I'm guessing there's something missing in your references to the SDK, it might not only be pointing the files. We don't know exactly how you referenced these files, it's not typically something that's expected to be done in this nature.

Comment: When creating new SDK inside of RAD itself, you have to point to the location of SDK folder, NDK folder, and based on this, it found (or sometimes not, in my case it did!) all of the necessary files in order to run. It did create SDK, it did recognize the version and platform, so referencing path is surely ok. Also, as already stated, the Sample project works and compiles just fine.

Comment: @JerryDodge: If you know nothing about XE5 and Android, you should avoid the question entirely. The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com) is free (as is Android itself) from Google, and the SDK is similar to the Windows SDK. (It's necessary for documentation/use of functionality. The installation is part of the XE5 mobile support, but the install (and IDE itself afterward) can be configured to use a different version of the SDK.

Comment: @JustMarc: Re-run the IDE installation, and during that install indicate that you don't want to install the SDK. After installing, use the IDE's SDK Manager (Tools->Options) to point to the proper location on your local machine. Downloading the SDK *is required* for the proper functionality of the compiler and IDE, even if you're not using the emulator. This is documented in the installation's readme file; the SDK requires a local path location. Note that the SDK has to be properly configured (there are environment variables to be set) for things to work properly.

Comment: @KenWhite as stated above, I do have SDK downloaded, it's on a local path - network drive, but that still applies as local, as it's mapped as the drive;  All variables are fine (Had troubles with Java JDK, but solved with another installation of it).
The SDK for IDE itself must be ok, since it does compile and even run directly on the device, if opened sample project. The otherone, however, throws undefined reference errors...
This is exaxtly why I posted the question - as it seems like project-specific. :/

Comment: Your text is confusing again: "The SDK for IDE itself must be ok, since it does compile and even run", but your entire question is about a failure "Undefined reference xxx when **compiling**". ??? What **exactly** is your question? Right now, it seems like "Compiling fails but it compiles and runs fine". What is "The otherone"? What was the first one, and where is an "otherone" mentioned?

Comment: You didn't read the entire sentence: IF opened SAMPLE project. The OTHERONE (meant mine, which can be noticed in the error log above) doesn't. Again, because the sample project runs, and mine doesn't, but both are in the same parent folder, on the same drive, ran on the same machine in the same ID, I think it must be something with in-project paths. On local machine directly, (on host, NOT VM OS), both compile just fine.
Is it any clearer now...? :/

Comment: Yes. The last was my fault, not yours. I should have referred back to your original question, instead of just responding to your comment itself. My mistake, and my apologies. :-) I have no more ideas, because I've not tried to do both (install in a VM and the local machine, with the SDK installed on a mapped drive). If you're installing the SDK in one location to save space, but have the IDE on both the host and VM, perhaps you should just install both the IDE and SDK on either the local drive or in the VM (but at least together somewhere).

Comment: No prob. :)
Hm, no, actually I deleted the IDE on host, reinstalled only to see if it works for sure.
The reason I moved IDE there was due to it's trial version usage and simplifying reinstallations of it. (I can't afford to buy xe5 just yet... Have xe3 licensed from a former sister's partner, who had it bought for a firm though...)
So no, I don't have ide on both, and spare space with sdk only. :) I even deleted files of rad in ProgramData, where it keeps entire installation's backup -.- On a 160GB ssd, it's too much. :/

Will dig further hopinf to find a solution... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A HA!

Seems like I succeeded in solving this!

As stated in comments above, the SDK for sure works, IDE as well, the only difference was the project.

I drilled around for a while now, and looks like finally got the solution which works!

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=626522

On the topic above, somewhere's stated and suggested to **run Build** separatelly, and then afterwards try to compile and run.

After running Build, and solving some minor errors and warnings that appeared (due to my fault, such as Icons location not being changed to network drive path), the Compiler simply got through and ran the application on the device! :O

So, re-building the program did the trick. :/

I'm sorry if this was quite obvious for some, but me, I always only did "Compile and Run" command ever since I'm in delphi, so haven't even thought of trying this.

Anyway, I hope this however won't be noted as junk question... :)

Comment: Hi.. do  you mind posting again the link, or eventually copying the relevant part? It is gone right now.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, I don't have any other link or the actual article saved anywhere...


But fortunatelly for you/us, I was at the right mind enough to actually write the solution in the comment too. :)
As written above, just try to use "Build" function before Run, and it should solve you an issue, if it's the same as I had.

you will find Build option if you right click on the Exe name (project name) in the "Project manager" on the right side of the screen.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150312055722/http://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=626522

Comment: You are the hero of my weekend, I was stuck at this problem the entire work week, tried everything and it didn't work. Of course this is not an obvious question, thank you for asking and answering it!